# DataBinder not binding JSON array object to List field in Model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is the javascript code that I'm using to create a JSON object with which to return values to a controller. vm Refers to an array elsewhere which is populated by numbers. I create an object that is an array of numbers.

```
$("#saveUser").live("click", function() {

            var username = $("#UserName").val();
            var email = $("#Email").val();
            var phoneNumber = $("#PhoneNumber").val();
            var personCode = $("#PersonCode").val();
            var managerId = $("#ManagerId").val();
            var officeId = $("#OfficeId").val();
            var address = $("#Address").val();
            var activeInd = $("#ActiveInd").val();

            var roles = [];
            for(i=0;i<vm.RoleDdList().length ;i++) {
                    roles.push(vm.RoleDdList()[i].role());   
                }

            var jsonObj = 
                {
                    username:username,
                    email:email,
                    phoneNumber:phoneNumber,
                    personCode:personCode,
                    managerId:managerId,
                    officeId:officeId,
                    address:address,
                    activeInd:activeInd,
                    roles:roles
            };


            $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               async:true,
               url:"Users/Save",
               data:jsonObj,
               dataType: "json",
               success:function (data) {
                   dlg.dialog("close");
               },
               error:function (data) 
               {
                   alert("An error occurred when saving the contact.");    
               }
            });
        });
```

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Save(UsersModel model)
    {
        //code
    }
```

I can see using the debugger that the roles field is not being passed to the controller. It is generated and populated though on the client side. The model expects a List of strings for that particular field. All of the other objects are passed through and matched up.

I have altered the code to convert the numbers in the vm array to be strings but I still get nothing passed through. (The List in the model is null).

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    url: '/Users/Save', 
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj), 
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    success: function (data) { 
        console.debug(data); 
    }, 
    error: function (data) { 
        console.debug(data); 
    } 
});
```